# Calculate per-minute day of week averages in R

Tags: r, data-analysis

I've collected data once a minute for the last 80 days, equaling about 116k records:

```
...
"30694","2015-09-06 18:09:11","119"
"30695","2015-09-06 18:10:09","693"
"30696","2015-09-06 18:11:10","155"
...
```

I want to be able to graph a whole-week average of this data. How should I do this in R? I was thinking of splitting the data into each day ([Sunday, Monday, ..., Saturday]) and then taking the average of each for minute (so just disregard seconds), equaling 60 * 24 * 7  = 10,080 total averages for the week, each average being computed by 80 days worth of data at a certain minute (i.e. 18:11). Is there an easier/better way to do this? Would also be open to using another data analysis package.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily using lubridate.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data %>%
  setNames(c("ID", "time", "measurement") ) %>%
  mutate(time = time %>% ymd_hms,
         week = time %>% round_date("week") ) %>%
  group_by(week) %>%
  summarize(measurement = mean(measurement))
```